# Управление скоростью CD привода.

Tags: c#

Как на C# управлять скоростью вращения CD привода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть [функция](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(v=VS.85).aspx) для управления устройствами. Подробнее [здесь.](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/DeviceIoControl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, функции мультимедиа (через PInvoke) дают доступ к скорости вращения привода (я не уверен):

- [mciSendString Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757161(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Multimedia Command Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743572(v=vs.85).aspx)